# Figuring out the value for PI

Tags: javascript, math

Let's say I have a function called bars()

```
bars () {
 const bars = []
 for (let i = 0; i < this.numberOfBars; i++) {
   bars.push(Math.sqrt(this.numberOfBars * this.numberOfBars - i * i))
 }
return bars
}
```

If I'm reducing the bars array to approximate PI, what should be on the right side of the arrow function?

```
PI = bars().reduce((a, b) =>
```

I tried adding the values and dividing by the number of bars, but I'm not getting anywhere near the approximation of Pi. I feel like there's a simple trick that I'm missing.

Comment: What makes you think that this is a method to calculate pi?

Comment: I believe if the bars were to be displayed visually, it would look like a quarter of a circle. That's why I thought there might be a way to do it using 4 * (bar_sum) / num_bars. It didn't work the way I expected it to though. There's some trick to this that I'm not able to spot.

Comment: Are you aware of the existance of Math.PI?
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/PI?retiredLocale=de)

Comment: The idea is to approximate Pi based on the number of bars.

Comment: Unsure why you are using square root when calulatingthe area when it is `π = A / r²`. You should be adding up all the area of the bars and diving it by the radius squared.

Comment: Why can't use simply use `Math.PI` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your funcion seems to list lengths of "bars" in a quarter of a circle, so we have to add them all up (to have the area of the quarter of a circle), then multiply by 4 (because there is 4 quarter) and the divide by `this.numberOfBars` ^ 2 because `area = π * r^2`, but like we have to know the radius, it is better using a pure function :

```js
// Your function rewritten as a pure one
const bars = numberOfBars => {
    const bars = []

    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfBars; i++) {
        bars.push(Math.sqrt(numberOfBars * numberOfBars - i * i))
    }

    return bars
}

// Here we take 1000 bars as an example but in your case you replace it by this.numberOfBars
// Sum them all up, multiply by 4, divide by the square of the radius
const PI = bars(1000).reduce((g, c) => g + c) * 4 / Math.pow(1000, 2)

console.log(PI)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
/** Approximates PI using geometry 
  * You get a better approximation using more bars and a smaller step size
*/
function approximatePI(numberOfBars, stepSize) {
    const radius = numberOfBars * stepSize;

    // Generate bars (areas of points on quarter circle)
    let bars = [];

    // You can think of i as some point along the x-axis
    for (let i = 0; i < radius; i += stepSize) {
        let height = Math.sqrt(radius*radius - i*i)
        bars.push(height * stepSize);
    }

    // Add up all the areas of the bars 
    // (This is approximately the area of a quarter circle if stepSize is small enough)
    const quarterArea = bars.reduce((a, b) => a + b);

    // Calculate PI using area of circle formula
    const PI = 4 * quarterArea / (radius*radius)
    return PI;
}


console.log(`PI is approximately ${approximatePI(100_000, 0.001)}`);
```

Comment: How would you guys refactor this so then the answer can come directly from the reduce()? Could we manipulate the a and b somehow to add up small components that'll approximate to Pi?

Comment: [Lukasbk38](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20480528/lucasbk38)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74436789/11485839) is the best you can do I think. Mathematically, you could put the `4/radius^2` constant inside the reduce function, but in JS the numerical errors will pile up a lot so best to factor it outside the reduce function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to push all terms to an array, then to reduce the array by addition. Just use an accumulator variable and add all terms to it.

---

Notice that the computation becomes less and less accurate the closer you get to the end of the radius. If you sum to half of the radius, you obtain r²(3√3+π)/24, from which you can draw π.

(Though in any case, this is one of the worst methods to evaluate π.)